# Document Root Change in Cpanel

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, cpanel, web-hosting

I recently purchased a web hosting plan with Godaddy. They use a program called cPanel to host the specified website (This is a Linux based machine). I recently added my website up to the file manager, but found I needed to change the document root. I got SSH working and went to the website directory folder and attempted to modify the root directory of my website. Upon completion of this I saved the file, but was met with a Permission Denied error. I did some more reading into how to change the file permissions to allow me to do so and have came up empty handed.

Thank you for your time

Comment: You should contact GoDaddy support.  Even if how you configure your GoDaddy account was on topic, you have not provided, enough information to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cPanel sites have a global setting for website root directories. You cannot change this without modifying the root vhosts file, which you should not have access to (If you do, please let GoDaddy know that their system is broken).

By default, cPanel servers use `/home/<username>/public_html/` as the root for the primary domain of an account. You can create addon or subdomains in cPanel with another root, as long as this root is inside your home directory (`/home/<username>`).

Answer (score 0):

Via SSH, remove the standard root directory alltogether and create a symlink in its place, pointing to the directory you want to use instead.

`rm -Rf /home/<username>/public_html/`

`ln -s /home/<username>/path/to/site/public_html/ /home/<username>/public_html/`